# In $\triangle ABC$, $AD$ is the altitude and $CE$ is the bisector. Find $\angle EDB$ if $\angle CEA = 45^\circ$.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles

Recently I took part in a mathematics Olympiad. There were 25 questions for 2 hours, and I couldn’t solve this problem, I’ll be glad if you help me with this:

> In $\triangle ABC$, $AD$ is the altitude and $CE$ is the bisector. Find $\angle EDB$ if $\angle CEA = 45^\circ$.

this is 9 class olympic, task ball is 1.5

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It seems the given conditions are not enough to determine $\angle EDB$.

Comment: if this is true, then this is very strange

Comment: This can be done [analytically](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ig3yldv9be), and the answer is $45^\circ$, I am not yet able to find a nice geometric solution

Answer (score 6):

[image]

In the figure, $F$ is a point on $BC$ such that $CF=CA$.

Join the lines as shown.

Note that $\Delta CEF \cong \Delta CEA  $ (SAS).

$\therefore \angle CEF=\angle CEA=45^{\text o}$ and hence $\angle AEF=90^{\text o}.$

Together with $AE=EF, $ we have $\angle EAF=45^{\text o}.$

Note also that $\angle ADC= \angle AEF=90^{\text o}$.

$\therefore A, D, F, E$ are concyclic.

Hence $\angle EDF=\angle EAF=45^{\text o}.$

$\therefore \angle EDB=45^{\text o}.$

Comment: Sory but i don't understand why ∠EDF=∠EAF=45

Comment: @SaykaGeom angles in the same segment are equal.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As can be seen in figure:

$\angle CEA=45^o=\frac 12(\overset {\large\frown} {AL}+\overset {\large\frown} {BM})$

the extension of DE meets the circle at G and  we have:

$LM||GA\Rightarrow \overset {\large\frown} {AL}=\overset {\large\frown} {MG}$

which deduces $\angle EDB=\angle CEA=45^o$